# Discord bot that moves people based on game activity

Tags: discord.js

Hello everyone I'm new to coding but I want to code the bot mentioned in the title so my questions are:
-Is there a command that reads the game activity?
-What is the command that makes the bot move someone?

I set the basics up but don't really know where to go from here:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();


client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Online');
});


client.login('*the token*');
```

Comment: There are no "commands", you have to use the library and interact with Classss and Objects. This is not a code writing service, you might want to check out the [Discord.JS Documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome)

Comment: I know but I don't know what I'm looking for?

Comment: I'd recommend you take a look at the [`presenceUpdate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-presenceUpdate) event then.

Answer (score 0):

All of a user's game activities are stored as an array, `activities`, within the `presence` property of your `user` object.

For example, if you want to get the game statuses of the author of a message, you can use `<message>.author.presence.activities` to get that array.  However, since a user may have multiple statuses (custom statuses, games, Rich Presences, etc), you'll generally want to get a specific activity.

If you need to check if the name of the status is a certain one, you'll need to get the specific index first, such as `<message>.author.presence.activities[0].name`.  If you want to check each status and see if any of them align with a needed name, you can use a [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop.

For more information, [here is the documentation on the presence of a user](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Presence).

As for "moving someone," you are not giving any more explanation as to what you mean, so that should be implemented once your bot can properly detect certain games.

In the meantime, try following a guide on how to turn user input into actual commands, and then this may make more sense if you are still facing issues.